# img Inside a foreignObject Inside an svg Inside an img

Tags: html, svg

Here is my test case.

http://tobeythorn.com/isi/dummy2.svg

http://tobeythorn.com/isi/isitest.html

- If I just open the svg by itself, the inner img is rendered fine.
- But when I make this svg the src of an img, the inner img is not rendered. I receive no errors.
- If I make the inner img a data-url, it gets rendered. If possible, I would like to avoid data-urls, as they complicate things, have size limitations, and cannot be cached.
- The same thing happens in FF, Chrome, Opera, and Safari.

I can't find a solution, but possibly related: [foreignObject inside second SVG element for Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15971905/foreignobject-inside-second-svg-element-for-chrome)

Cross-origin issue?

Limitation of the spec?

Browser bug?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 4):

All SVGs used as images must be complete in a single file. Images cannot load external data.

So you need to [base64 encode](https://www.base64encode.org/) the image and embed it into the SVG as a [data URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#HTML) to get it to work.

Comment: I need to solve this as well, and I'm not sure how to do what you described. Can you add more detail?

Comment: @brainbag What in particular? How to do base64 encoding? Or how to create a data URL. There are online encoders and wikipedia or other sources describe data URLs. I've added some links to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see your example, but if you using JS to append a html element to svg, you must remember using prefix to tell browser that this element is svg or html.

For example, if you append a html img element:

```
$('svg').append('svg:foreignObject').append('xhtml:img').attr('src','./foo.jpg');
```