# Why doesn't my SVG data URL inside HTML inside an SVG data url show in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, svg, html5-canvas

### Background

I have an SVG data URL as a `background-image` property of an HTML element inside a `<foreignObject>` inside an SVG data URL which serves as the source of an `<img>` element.

### Problem

In Google Chrome, that inner SVG is not rendered at all; while if this whole business wasn't inside an image, it would have rendered. How can I solve this?

> Wait, what? Why?

A *why* will be below, but first I want to complete the question by adding a tree structure and a code sample, to clarify the above convoluted paragraph.

Tree:

- `<img src="data:image/svg+xml;utf8,` (exhibit **A**)

  - `<svg>` (exhibit **B**)

    - `<foreignObject>`

      - `<html>`

        - `<div style="background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,`

          - `<svg>` (exhibit **C**)

Exhibit C is not rendered at all, as if it's not there. If I cut exhibit A out, though, so that exhibit B is the top-level element, then exhibit C is rendered fine.

Small code sample:

```html
<div>Standalone:</div>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="75" height="50" style="position:relative"><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25" fill="red" /><foreignObject style="width: 100%; height: 100%"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><style>.x {position: absolute;background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='50'><circle cx='50' cy='25' r='25' fill='blue'/></svg>"); width: 100%; height: 100%;}</style><div class="x"></div></html></foreignObject></svg>

<div>As image source:</div>
<img style="position:relative" src='data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="75" height="50" style="position:relative"><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25" fill="red" /><foreignObject style="width: 100%; height: 100%"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><style>.x {position: absolute;background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2000/svg&quot; width=&quot;100&quot; height=&quot;50&quot;><circle cx=&quot;50&quot; cy=&quot;25&quot; r=&quot;25&quot; fill=&quot;blue&quot;/></svg>"); width: 100%; height: 100%;}</style><div class="x"></div></html></foreignObject></svg>'>
```

One final note: using a PNG data URL instead of an SVG data URL works well; it's when using SVG when this becomes broken.

### Why?

Placing HTML inside an `<img>` allows that HTML to be rendered on a canvas by `context.drawImage` - and I follow that up by `canvas.toDataURL` in order to generate an image from the HTML, which is my ultimate goal. This is a terrible though standard approach, also employed by widely-used libraries such as https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image.

My HTML comes with its own embedded SVG, though, which creates the problem mentioned in the question. Until now I bypassed this by first repeating this flow for the innermost SVG data URLs, replacing them with PNG data URLs, and only then rendering the top-level HTML element. But now I want to add scaling to the mix, which greatly complicates things, since those PNGs won't scale smoothly and I can't scale first because then the images will be too big for their elements.

(well it works okay with background-image which scales, but not with clip-path which doesn't scale and I'm also converting).

### Other browsers

IE and Edge do not support HTML inside `<foreignObject>`, so this is irrelevant for them.

Firefox does support it but for some reason its "standalone" version doesn't work either - which I would also like to solve but it might belong in a separate question.

### Related but not duplicates:

- [Append foreignObject containing some HTML inside an SVG element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38437834/append-foreignobject-containing-some-html-inside-an-svg-element) - is about a missing namespace declaration.
- [img Inside a foreignObject Inside an svg Inside an img](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27996818/img-inside-a-foreignobject-inside-an-svg-inside-an-img) - is about external images, not data URLs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to encode special characters, I don't know exactly which one was the culprit, but when using encodeURIComponent on the whole <CSSImage url>, then encoding again the whole markup to pass it in the <img>, everything works fine in Chrome.

```html
<div>Standalone:</div>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="75" height="50" style="position:relative"><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25" fill="red" /><foreignObject style="width: 100%; height: 100%"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><style>.x {position: absolute;background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20width%3D'100'%20height%3D'50'%3E%3Ccircle%20cx%3D'50'%20cy%3D'25'%20r%3D'25'%20fill%3D'blue'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E"); width: 100%; height: 100%;}</style><div class="x"></div></html></foreignObject></svg>

<div>As image source:</div>
<img style="position:relative" src="data:image/svg+xml;utf8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%2275%22%20height%3D%2250%22%20style%3D%22position%3Arelative%22%3E%3Ccircle%20cx%3D%2225%22%20cy%3D%2225%22%20r%3D%2225%22%20fill%3D%22red%22%20%2F%3E%3CforeignObject%20style%3D%22width%3A%20100%25%3B%20height%3A%20100%25%22%3E%3Chtml%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxhtml%22%3E%3Cstyle%3E.x%20%7Bposition%3A%20absolute%3Bbackground%3A%20url(%22data%3Aimage%2Fsvg%2Bxml%3Butf8%2C%253Csvg%2520xmlns%253D'http%253A%252F%252Fwww.w3.org%252F2000%252Fsvg'%2520width%253D'100'%2520height%253D'50'%253E%253Ccircle%2520cx%253D'50'%2520cy%253D'25'%2520r%253D'25'%2520fill%253D'blue'%252F%253E%253C%252Fsvg%253E%22)%3B%20width%3A%20100%25%3B%20height%3A%20100%25%3B%7D%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22x%22%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3C%2Fhtml%3E%3C%2FforeignObject%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E">
```

Also note that `<foreingObject>`'s `width` and `height` attributes are mandatory in SVG1.1, and thus, omitting them will work only in Chrome.

So for other browsers that still have to implement this new feature

```html
<div>Standalone:</div>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="75" height="50" style="position:relative"><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25" fill="red" /><foreignObject width="100%" height="100%"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><style>.x {position: absolute;background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20width%3D'100'%20height%3D'50'%3E%3Ccircle%20cx%3D'50'%20cy%3D'25'%20r%3D'25'%20fill%3D'blue'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E"); width: 100%; height: 100%;}</style><div class="x"></div></html></foreignObject></svg>

<div>As image source:</div>
<img style="position:relative" src="data:image/svg+xml;utf8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%2275%22%20height%3D%2250%22%20style%3D%22position%3Arelative%22%3E%3Ccircle%20cx%3D%2225%22%20cy%3D%2225%22%20r%3D%2225%22%20fill%3D%22red%22%20%2F%3E%3CforeignObject%20width%3D%22100%%22%20height%3D%22100%%22%3E%3Chtml%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxhtml%22%3E%3Cstyle%3E.x%20%7Bposition%3A%20absolute%3Bbackground%3A%20url(%22data%3Aimage%2Fsvg%2Bxml%3Butf8%2C%253Csvg%2520xmlns%253D'http%253A%252F%252Fwww.w3.org%252F2000%252Fsvg'%2520width%253D'100'%2520height%253D'50'%253E%253Ccircle%2520cx%253D'50'%2520cy%253D'25'%2520r%253D'25'%2520fill%253D'blue'%252F%253E%253C%252Fsvg%253E%22)%3B%20width%3A%20100%25%3B%20height%3A%20100%25%3B%7D%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22x%22%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3C%2Fhtml%3E%3C%2FforeignObject%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E">
```

Comment: Here's a link for everyone to encode svg html element instead of using encodeURIComponent function, much easier. [URL encode and decode Tool](https://www.onlinewebtoolkit.com/url-encode-decode#)